# Taglist mapping of tab key

Tags: vim, taglist

I have mapped the `TAB` key to move between windows as shown below.

```
map <TAB> ^W^W
```

It works for all the windows (for example split-screen) except for the taglist window. When I press the TAB key in the taglist window, it either does not goto next window. How can I override it?

I also configured following options in my `.vimrc`:

```
let Tlist_Show_One_File = 1
let Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow = 1
let Tlist_WinWidth = 30
```

It works if I comment out following line in `taglist.vim` plugin file

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <Tab> :call <SID>Tlist_Window_Move_To_File(1)<CR>
```

I tried adding following line in my `.vimrc` file, but it didn't work.

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <Tab> ^W^W
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the Taglist plugin creates its own buffer-local mapping for its sidebar.

There's no general way to undo / override that. Fortunately, the Taglist plugin creates its sidebar with a particular name (`__Tag_List__`), so you can hook into that with an `:autocmd`:

```
:autocmd BufEnter __Tag_List__ silent! nunmap <buffer> <Tab>
```

The `silent!` suppresses errors if the mapping has already been cleared.